# Xamarin Forms Geolocator IOS

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am running into an issue with a project that I am working on. I recently began learning C# and have successfully built a basic program in Xamarin Forms.

I am diving into a fairly large project and continuing to learn along the way.

The issue that I am currently experiencing is with generating a map page that centers on the current location of the device. I have narrowed down the issue to what I believe is the location once it is obtained is not being saved to the variable that I have declared  so that I can access it in another method.

```
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{

        public static double latitude;
        public static double longitude;

    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        GetCurrentLocation();

        var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
            new Position(latitude, longitude), Distance.FromMiles(.3)))
        {
            MapType = MapType.Street,
            IsShowingUser = true,
            HeightRequest = 100,
            WidthRequest = 960,
            VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
            HasScrollEnabled = true,
            HasZoomEnabled = true
        };

        var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
        stack.Children.Add(map);
        Content = stack;
    }


    private static async void GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);

        latitude = position.Latitude;
        longitude = position.Longitude;
    }
}
```

When the map is displayed using the code above it is receiving (0,0) for the latitude and longitude. I have verified using breakpoints and debugging that the latitude and longitude are being retrieved and stored in the "position" variable however I don't believe it is being stored in my latitude and longitude variables.

Any idea of what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public async override void OnAppearing()
{
    var pos = await GetCurrentLocation();

    var map = new Map(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(
        pos, Distance.FromMiles(.3)))
    {
        MapType = MapType.Street,
        IsShowingUser = true,
        HeightRequest = 100,
        WidthRequest = 960,
        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
        HasScrollEnabled = true,
        HasZoomEnabled = true
    };

    var stack = new StackLayout { Spacing = 0 };
    stack.Children.Add(map);
    Content = stack;
}

private async Position GetCurrentLocation()
{
    var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
    locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

    var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);

    return position;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are **several things you should take care** in your code:

- method 'GetCurrentLocation()' that retrieve the location is async. If it fails, your app fails. You should at less use a try{ } catch{} inside this method. Personaly, for readability, I also add 'Async' suffix to async methods (ie: GetCurrentLoactionAsync()).
- Next you call your 'async' method from the constructor. But in your constructor, you CAN'T await an async method (wait for the result). That's why you always have a null position. You should not call this method from here.
- as mentionned @Jason, you can override 'OnAppearing()' method to load your data. It's a better place for that. But take care to use the 'await' keyword and call the method in a try/catch block as 'OnAppearing()' doesn't return a Task.
- Finally I suggest you to create your map in your XAML code part (so the map already exists and you will not have a blank page until the position is loaded). Then in OnAppearing() you initialize the map with the posistion (it will probably generate an animation on the map by recentering it. It's more pleasant I think ;).

### XAML Part:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="MediaSample.MapPage">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Grid>

        <!-- your map object -->
        <Map x:Name="uiMap" />

        <!-- whatever you want -->

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

### Code behind part:

```
[XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
public partial class MapPage : ContentPage
{
    public MapPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        try
        {
            // get your position
            var centerPos = await GetCurrentLocation();

            // init map => center on the position
            uiMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(centerPos, Distance.FromMiles(.3)).WithZoom(20));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // notify user here
            // log exception
        }
    }

    private async Task<Position> GetCurrentLocation()
    {
        var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
        locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;

        var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(timeoutMilliseconds: 10000);

        return position;
    }
}
```